# Setting routes in node

Tags: node.js, routes

I have a module that calculates the area and circumference of a circle. This module has two functions, `area` and `circumference` which are calculated based on the value of the radius passed in. In my code I import this module and call it `var t`. What I'm trying to do is output the value of the area or circumference depending on the value passed to the url. 
i.e : If the url were to be `localhost:8080/circ/4` the page would display "The value of the circumference is + t(4)" AND if the url were to be `localhost:8080/area/4` it would display "The value of the area is + t(4)".

I know how to write it using express and hapi, but how would I set the routes using just pure node so that it takes `request.params.value` where `value` is the value of the radius? I can't find any examples and most examples use express.

```
var http = require('http');
var t = require('./modules/myModule.js');


var server = http.createServer();


server.on("request", function(request, response){
    console.log("Request received!");
    response.writeHead (200, {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("The value of the circumfrence is ");
    response.end();
  }
);

server.listen(8080);
console.log("Server running on port 8080");
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, node doesn't parse params out of your request url, you'll have to do that yourself. One approach would be to use a regular expression to match each route. An example, based on yours, that implements the circ endpoint:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(request, response){
    // console.log('Request received!');
    var circUrlRegex =/^\/circ\/(\d+)$/;
    var match = circUrlRegex.exec(request.url);
    if (match) {
        var radius = parseInt(match[1], 10);
        var circumference = 2*Math.PI*radius;
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
        response.write('The value of the circumfrence is ' + circumference);
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(404);
    }
    response.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Of course if you want to add additional routes, dumping everything into the request event handler quickly becomes unmaintainable. Then you might want to build a system to register routes, and have the handler loop over them one by one until a match is found.

One last thing: you might want to check out [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/). It is a well-supported library for building api's, without all the cruft Express comes with.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. Although you don't use the module that I import, this still helps me understand what needs to be done. Could I use node's `url` module to parse params from my request url?

Comment: I don't know what interface the module you imported has, so I can't help you there :). The url module does have a parse function, that can  take care of query string parameters, see the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost). 'Ordinary' parameters you'll have to take care of yourself. Its probably not a bad idea to parse using `url.parse` first, then use the regex matching on the pathname property of the returned object.